# Change bar stack background by boolean value

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a bar chart that (for me) is complex, it takes a list of employees, each employee has a list of employeeProjects and it shows the different projects an employee works on for a given year. Employees on the X axis and Months on the Y axis. The bar chart is stacked with each project and months for each employee.

Recently Ive added a confirmBooking boolean to the employeeProject, now what Id like is for the graph to stay as is but if confirmBooking is false I'd like to have the background look different. For example diagonal lines darker than the generated color or just the border with the generated color and the background grey.

Here is a working codepen: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/BaxjwWM I've added my code below as its slightly different to the codepen but you get the idea (sorry I couldnt get codepen to work with my updated js). So how can I change only the background of a bar stack if the confirmBooking is false?

Here is my current chart javascript:

```
const labels = listEmployees.reduce(function(result, item) {
  result.push(item.name);
  return result;
}, []);

const randomColorGenerator = function () {
  return '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) + '0000000').slice(2, 8);
};

const projects = listEmployees.reduce(function(result, item) {
  item.employeeProjects.forEach(function(prj){
    const prjId = prj.project.id;
    if (!result[prjId]) {
      result[prjId] = {
        label: prj.project.name,
        data: [],
        backgroundColor: randomColorGenerator()
      };
    }
  });
  return result;
}, {});

listEmployees.forEach(function(item) {
  for (const prjId of Object.keys(projects)) {
    const prj = projects[prjId];
    const empPrjs = item.employeeProjects.filter(el => el.project.id === parseFloat(prjId));
    if (empPrjs.length) {
      const totalMonths = empPrjs.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.employeeBookedMonths, 0);
      prj.data.push(totalMonths);
    } else {
      prj.data.push(0);
    }
  }
});

const horizontalArbitraryLine = {
    id: 'horizontalArbitraryLine',
    beforeDraw(chart, args, options) {
        const {ctx, chartArea: {top, right, bottom, left, width, height}, scales:
        {x, y} } = chart;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
        ctx.strokeRect(left, y.getPixelForValue(12), width, 1);
    }
};

const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: Object.values(projects)
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [horizontalArbitraryLine]
});
```

And example data with the confirmBooking, it has 2 different employees, each with 2 different employeeProjects with one being true, the other false.

````
```[{"id":46,"firstName":"Kayd","lastName":"AASSave","name":"Kayd AASSave","contractedFrom":"2023-04-01","contractedTo":"2023-04-30","employeeProjects":[{"id":77,"project":{"id":7,"projectNumber":343434,"name":"Casablanca","startDate":"2022-09-01","endDate":"2025-08-31","projectLengthInMonths":12,"currentBookedMonths":3,"remainingBookedMonths":30,"numberOfEmployees":0,"comment":"Another comment"},"employeeBookedMonths":1,"employeeProjectStartDate":"2023-03-01","employeeProjectEndDate":"2023-03-31","employeeProjectName":"Casablanca","confirmBooking":false},{"id":79,"project":{"id":4,"projectNumber":123123,"name":"Kost","startDate":"2023-01-01","endDate":"2023-12-31","projectLengthInMonths":12,"currentBookedMonths":4,"remainingBookedMonths":10,"numberOfEmployees":0,"comment":"No date sets for Kost"},"employeeBookedMonths":1,"employeeProjectStartDate":"2023-04-01","employeeProjectEndDate":"2023-04-30","employeeProjectName":"Kost","confirmBooking":true},{"id":73,"project":{"id":1,"projectNumber":12345,"name":"Test Project","startDate":"2023-01-01","endDate":"2023-12-31","projectLengthInMonths":12,"currentBookedMonths":12,"remainingBookedMonths":-11,"numberOfEmployees":0,"comment":"12 month project"},"employeeBookedMonths":1,"employeeProjectStartDate":"2023-05-01","employeeProjectEndDate":"2023-05-31","employeeProjectName":"Test Project","confirmBooking":false}],"projectIds":null,"startDates":null,"endDates":null},

{"id":45,"firstName":"TestName","lastName":"AddProjectName","name":"TestName AddProjectName","contractedFrom":"2023-04-01","contractedTo":"2023-04-30","employeeProjects":[{"id":72,"project":{"id":6,"projectNumber":212121,"name":"Slafe","startDate":"2022-01-01","endDate":"2023-10-31","projectLengthInMonths":10,"currentBookedMonths":3,"remainingBookedMonths":17,"numberOfEmployees":0,"comment":"Yay"},"employeeBookedMonths":1,"employeeProjectStartDate":"2023-02-02","employeeProjectEndDate":"2023-03-31","employeeProjectName":"Slafe","confirmBooking":true}],"projectIds":null,"startDates":null,"endDates":null}
````